# Cannot get audio to play in JavaScript soundboard (total newbie here)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create, as a starting excercise, a soundboard for our D&D sessions. I'm currently trying to make it so that when a button is clicked, the variable 'audio' is set to that, and that it then runs the function to play or pause audio, depending on whether it's running or not. I have JS and HTML in the same file (I realise this isn't good, however). Below is my code:

```
    <button id="play1st">Heroic Battle Music</button>
    <button id="play2nd">Military Battle Music</button>
    <button id="play3rd">Stronghold Battle Music</button>

 <!--Audio to be played -->
        <audio id="heroic" src="heroic.mp3"></audio>
        <audio id="combat_rome" src="combat_rome.mp3"></audio>
        <audio id="stronghold" src="stronghold.mp3"></audio>

        <!--JavaScript audio -->
        <script>
        function playMusic() {
        document.getElementById("play1st").addEventListener ('click', music1());
        document.getElementById("play2nd").addEventListener ('click', music2());
        document.getElementById("play3rd").addEventListener ('click', music3());
        var isPlaying = false;
        function music1() {
          var audio = new Audio("heroic.mp3");
          togglePlay();
        };
        function music2() {
          var audio = new Audio("combat_rome.mp3");
          togglePlay();
        };
        function music3() {
          var audio = new Audio("stronghold.mp3");
          togglePlay();
        };

        function togglePlay(){
        if  (isPlaying){
          pause()
        } else {
          audio.play();
        }
        };
        audio.onplaying = function () {
          isPlaying = true;
        };

        audio.onpause = function () {
          isPlaying = false;
        }};
        </script>

I'm probably missing something very basic, so any explanation would be most welcome. Thank you!
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you get any error message? If so please add it to your question.

Comment: Is it just me missing it, or is the function `playMusic()` never called? I guess, that the `onclick`-events won't fire, since they get defined in the `playMusic()`-function, which never gets called. Just for fun, try removing the outer shell `function playMusic(){ [...] };`

Comment: I see numerous problems. Suggest you start by getting one sound file able to start/stop before compounding the same problems into multiple functions

Comment: @D.Schaller Correct, not a single function is being called in the HTML. (or event)

Comment: @D.Schaller Thank you for your comment! I tried removing it, but then get the following error message in chrome:Uncaught ReferenceError: audio is not defined
    at togglePlay (index.html:54)
    at music1 (index.html:39)
    at index.html:33